# Relative to java (Error while importing scanner)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation

Recently I'm doing my java code but came with an error and also I already imported Scanner class but when I compile the whole code it shows me error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kz20.png)

I'm expecting that it do not show the error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your class name `Scanner` conflicts with the in-built `Scanner` class. Rename your class name into any other non-conflicting names.